# CloudFormation Error: 'CodeUri' requires Bucket and Key properties to be specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam

I'm creating a Lambda through CloudFormation. The Function code path must be dynamic.

Here's my template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Parameters:
  LambdaBucketName:
    Type: String
    Description: The name S3 Bucket of the lambda function code


Resources:
  FUNC:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'my-lambda-func'
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      CodeUri:
        FunctionCode:
          Bucket: !Ref LambdaBucketName
          Key: my-lambda-func.zip

etc...
```

When it deploys, I get this Cfn error message:

> ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS : 'CodeUri' requires Bucket and Key properties to be specified.

But documentation says it's ok to do this. [AWS::Serverless::Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-codeuri)

> CodeUri
> The function code's Amazon S3 URI, path to local folder, or ***FunctionCode*** object.

If I use just this:
`CodeUri: s3://my-bucket/my-lambda-func.zip`

It's fine because it's not dynamic. But if I try using that with !Ref (mapping), it won't work. Complains about the pattern.

If I try:

```
CodeUri:
  Bucket: !Ref LambdaBucketName
  Key: my-lambda-func.zip
```

Then I get a pattern error on Bucket. The ref'd bucket name is just a normal short string.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since the following works:

```
CodeUri: s3://my-bucket/my-lambda-func.zip
```

you can make it dynamic using:

```
CodeUri: !Sub "s3://${LambdaBucketName}/my-lambda-func.zip"
```

Comment: for some reason I still get these error

Comment: @Stark Answer updated. Forgot about `$`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
  CodeUri:
    FunctionCode:
      Bucket: !Sub ${LambdaBucketName}
      Key: my-lambda-func.zip
```